# DROPBOX- Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001

Tags: ios, dropbox

I am trying to download some of the audio files from dropbox to my app. When the audio files are minimum upto 4 or 5 audiofiles the download doesn't cause any problem. But when it has greater than 5 audio files it cause error 1001. I searched for this issue and i found this is because of `TIMEOUT`.

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files/dropbox/xxx/xxx/xxx.ima4 - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" UserInfo=0x851b0a0 {path=/xxx/xxx/xxx.ima4, destinationPath=/Users/siva/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/xxx/xxx/Library/TempAttachment/xxx/xxx.ima4}
```

What can i do now? Any soution please

Answer (score 0):

What SDK are you using? (Core or Sync?)

If you're using the Core API and kicking off all these downloads in parallel, that may be the cause of the problem. You should consider doing the downloads one at a time (or a small number at a time) to avoid requests getting blocked on the limited bandwidth of the device.

Comment: I am using core,.. As for your idea it may takes so many duration to complete downloads,.. Thanks for your suggestion,..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the number of concurrent requests is to high.

You need to use something like an NSOperationQueue to limit the number of request made at any one time. Failing to do so you get the timeout -1001